# How do I draw the image of the following complex region under the power map?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

> Let me denote $R=\left\{0<Arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{6}\right\}$. I want to understand how $f(R)$ looks like if $f(z)=z^i$.

My idea was that I first compute the image for an arbitrary $z\in R$ and then try to draw it.

So let $z\in R$ then $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r\in (0,\infty)$ and $\theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$. Then $$f(z)=f(re^{i\theta})=e^{i(\log(r)+i\theta)}=\frac{1}{e^\theta}e^{i\log(r)}$$ Where $\theta\in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$ and $\log(r)\in (0,\infty)$

So now our new radius is $\frac{1}{e^\theta}$ and the new argument is $\log(r)$.

But this somehow seems a bit strange to me, is this really correct? And if yes how do I draw it now from here?

My idea is that the new radius let's denotes it $r'$ satisfies $\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\pi}{6}}}<r'<\frac{1}{e^0}=1$ but then the argument lies in $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @user2661923 ah okey but nevertheless I think something went wrong didn't it?

Comment: +1 to your question, for nice work shown.  If there is a mistake in your work, I can't find it.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks but can you also help me how I can sketch my area using the computation I did?

Comment: @user2661923 I somehow added an idea but also this do not help me drawing the picture

Comment: Your last sentence is correct. (Actually the argument is arbitrary real, but as soon as the interval of values is longer than $2\pi$ you an an entire annulus.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang so you mean if I draw it I have an entire annulus from $\frac{1}{e^\frac{\pi}{6}}$ to $1$ but it is somehow an annulus which is infinitely many often over itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request for mapping help:

Each ray (i.e. half line, emanating from the origin) of direction $\theta$ goes to a concentric circle of radius $e^{-\theta}.$

Along this ray, as $r$ goes from $0 < r$ to $r < \infty$, the argument $\log(r)$ will go from $-\infty$ to  $+\infty$.  Strangely, this is
of only arguable relevance, because it is obvious that you can find a subset of $r$ : $R_1 \leq r < R_2$ such that $\log(R_2) - \log(R_1) = 2\pi$.

This means that as $r$ takes on the values in $[R_1, R_2)$ that a complete revolution is traced out, along the circle of radius $e^{-i\theta}.$

So, the map should be represented by a **continuous** series of concentric circles, which is represented by the closed **donut**.  The inner radius of the donut is $e^{(-\pi/6)}$ and the outer radius is $e^{-0}$.

---

An alternate perspective is that if you hold $r$ fixed, with $\alpha = \log(r)$, and let $\theta$ take on the values in $[0,\pi/6]$, that a ray will be traced along the path $\alpha$, from radius $e^{(-\theta/6)}$ to $e^{(-0)}.$

Comment: Perfect thanks!